# Parsing multiple types in a JSON array with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am attempting to parse a JSON string using a POJO with gson, I have run into a snag however when attempting to read the following JSON array:

```
{"translate":"chat.type.text","with":[{"insertion":"woder22","clickEvent":{"action":"suggest_command","value":"/msg woder22 "},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":"{name:\"woder22\",id:\"bbd02ce0-24de-4683-8c8f-5d7e6b7dffa6\",}"},"text":"woder22"},"hi"]}
```

Everything works just fine until I get to the "with" part, I am trying to parse it by using the following POJOs

```
public class ChatMessage {
    private String text = "";
    private String translate;
    private List<With> with = new ArrayList<With>();
    private String score;
    private String selector;
    private List<Node> extra;
    private String bold = "false";
    private String italic = "false";
    private String underlined = "false";
    private String strikethrough = "false";
    private String obfuscated = "false";
    private String color;
    private Clicked clickEvent;
    private Hover hoverEvent;
    private String insertion;

    //getter and setter method here

}

class Node {
    private String color;
    private String text;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

class Clicked {
    private String action;
    private String value;

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Hover {
    private String action;
    private String value;

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I have changed this to show all of the code

```
public class With {
    private String translate;
    private Clicked clickEvent;
    private Hover hoverEvent;
    private String insertion;
    private String text = "";

    //setter and getters

    public ChatMessage getNonNull(ChatMessage mes){
        if(this.text != null)mes.setText(this.text);
        if(this.translate != null)mes.setTranslate(this.translate);
        if(this.score != null)mes.setScore(this.score);
        if(this.selector != null)mes.setSelector(this.selector);
        if(this.extra != null)mes.setExtra(this.extra);
        if(this.bold != null)mes.setBold(this.bold);
        if(this.italic != null)mes.setItalic(this.italic);
        if(this.underlined != null)mes.setUnderlined(this.underlined);
        if(this.strikethrough != null)mes.setStrikethrough(this.strikethrough);
        if(this.obfuscated != null)mes.setObfuscated(this.obfuscated);
        if(this.color != null)mes.setColor(this.color);
        if(this.clickEvent != null)mes.setClickEvent(this.clickEvent);
        if(this.hoverEvent != null)mes.setHoverEvent(this.hoverEvent);
        if(this.insertion != null)mes.setInsertion(this.insertion);
        return mes;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when Gson tries to parse this it of course runs into the problem that the second part of the "with" array is NOT a With object. My problem is that I have no idea how to deal with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit1 
What it is suppose to do:
The with array is simply suppose to be a sort of "overwrite" as in any field from the main string can be overwritten and individually formatted inside. Thats what the null thing at the bottom of the With class is suppose to do, it is suppose to edit the main variables with their overwritten contents. The unnamed field is suppose to be the text variable here.

Comment: What do you want to with this "hi" value? Store it in the list? Discard it?

Comment: Oh yeah - I'm trying to put it in a variable, in this case the "text" variable (its the actual text whereas the rest here is the formatting) if it helps any, here is the documentation on the actual json string used here: http://wiki.vg/Chat

Comment: The documentation you linked does not show this particular structure (speaking about the with array). Anyway you could write a custom deserializer to parse this JSON as you want.

Comment: Is there any chance you could put me on the right track for doing that? I'm rather new to Gson.

Comment: Sure but I'm not very sure about which final structure you need, so if you could clarify things that would help.

Comment: I have edited my question to include more details on what should be going on. I believe what I have written should cover everything. Thanks by the way!

Comment: I guess I understand what it's supposed to give. But talking about your initial problem this String "hi" should be stored in which variable? I don't see where it would be in the all structure you give.

Comment: The variable is called Text.

Comment: There are multiple variables called text. You're talking about the one in the With class? But shouldn't it be "woder22" and the one in ChatMessage shouldn't it be "Hello world" (in the example you gave). This "hi" string appears nowhere in your structure, unless I'm really blind...

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't noticed that! Okay sorry about the confusion! The "hi" is the actually chat message, so I suppose it would be fair to call it chattext that would be located inside the With class (since that is where we are parsing that part of the string). You have however made me realize that the "hi" really does appear nowhere, which is interesting.

Comment: But this is an array of With instances, so it should be put inside the first item in the array. Currently the structure is [With object, String hi].

Comment: Yeah - see this is back to the original problem. Every element in the with array is suppose to overwrite the stuff in ChatMessage. That being said when its a with object everything inside the object must overwrite the corresponding value in Chatmessage. In the case where its randomly there, so like with "hi", it should just directly override the corresponding field. (Please note I do not have control over the json string and I don't know why it was done like that)

Comment: Let's talk first about the parsing. When you'll have that you'll be able to overwrite what you need to overwrite. with can be a List<Object> with some With instances or the String hi. If it satisfies you I can show you how to get this. But I'm not sure what do you want to do with this String. It's intent is to replace the text value in the object? But there's already a text value that overwrites in the With object which makes things confusing. So what this value "hi" is supposed to do?

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm kinda guessing in that part too, I do know however that the end result should look as follows: "<woder22> hi" now how this is actually achieved doesn't really matter to me. From my observations however it would appear that the "text" variable ("woder22") seems to be the user name and the noname value ("hi") seems to be the actual message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you could write a custom deserializer for this:

```
class ChatMessageDezerializer implements JsonDeserializer<ChatMessage> {
    @Override
    public ChatMessage deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage();
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        message.translate = obj.get("translate").getAsString();
        JsonArray array = obj.getAsJsonArray("with");
        message.with.add(context.deserialize(array.get(0), With.class));
        message.with.add(array.get(1).getAsString());
        return message;
    }
}
```

and register it in your Gson parser:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ChatMessage.class, new ChatMessageDezerializer()).create();
```

Note that `with` is now a `List<Object>` since the most specific common type to the elements in the array are Object. Also I just done the problematic part, the rest can be handled easily. Running this you end up with

```
[With@b1a58a3, hi]
```

as the resulting list. This assume you have a minimum control over the structure you get back (or at least you know in which format it would be). It should give you a good starting point from there.

Comment: @Alexis, can you tell me something about Generic type the way you have implemented in code, I have little knowledge( like how to use in ArrayList<String>) about them and want to learn how to work with generics